# Find totally covered circles in a set of circles

Tags: algorithm, geometry

We have a set of circles in a rectangular area, all the circles have the same radii, I want to find the circles totally covered by other circles.
is there any algorithme for that ?

Comment: Look this post (it may be help): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68395/determine-if-circle-is-covered-by-some-set-of-other-circles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Geometry**

First, find all the circles whose center is closer than 2×r to the center of the main circle; circles further away do not overlap.

[image: overlapping circles]

<sup>Example: the main (black) circle and 3 overlapping circles.</sup>

Then, to know that the main circle is completely covered, you have to find a set of circles for which every intersecting point of two circles which lies within the main (black) circle, is covered by a third circle.

**Algorithm**

Practically, you start with 2 circles (e.g. blue and red), and find the 2 points where they intersect (purple dots). If one or both points are within the main (black) circle, then these points have to be covered by an additional circle.

Then, one by one, add an additional circle (e.g. green), and see whether it covers non-covered points (in the example it does). However, this new circle adds new intersection points with the other circles already in the set (blue and red); find these points (teal and brown dots) and check whether they are covered by any of the circles (the teal one is covered by the red circle, but the brown one is not covered by the blue circle).

Keep adding circles to the set until every intersection point inside the main (black) circle is covered by another circle in the set (in which case the whole main circle is covered), or until you run out of circles (in which case the main circle is not completely covered).

Special cases:
If one of the circles has the exact same center point as the main circle, it covers the main circle on its own.
If none of the circles have intersection points inside the main circle, the main circle is not covered.

**Code example**

This code example demonstrates how to find the intersecting points of two circles, which takes care of most of the geometry needed in the algorithm.

[image: intersecting points two circles]

```js
function intersections(p, q, r) {
    var d = distance(p, q);
    if (d > 2 * r) return [];
    var m = middle(p, q);
    if (d == 2 * r) return [m];
    var a = angle(p, q) + Math.PI / 2;
    var l = length(d, r);
    return [{x: m.x + l * Math.cos(a), y: m.y + l * Math.sin(a)},
            {x: m.x - l * Math.cos(a), y: m.y - l * Math.sin(a)}];

    function distance(p, q) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p.x - q.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.y - q.y, 2));
    }
    function middle(p, q) {
        return {x: (p.x + q.x) / 2, y: (p.y + q.y) / 2};
    }
    function angle(p, q) {
        return Math.atan2(q.y - p.y, q.x - p.x);
    }
    function length(d, r) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(d, 2) / 4);
    }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(intersections({x:1, y:2}, {x:3, y:-4}, 5)));
```

Comment: @lola As always when comparing distances, comparing distances squared will remove the need to calculate (time-consuming) square roots.